# Use of IDs and Classes issues in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and currently pulling my out my hair, because of an issue I don´t know how to resolve!

I'm trying to make a circle change its color based on a number that it is getting from my "Paragraph tag". When I used ID´s on my page I manage to make it work.

```js
(function() {
  var Antal = document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML;

  if (Antal >= 6) {
    document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
  } else
  if (Antal >= 1 && Antal < 5) {
    document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  } else
  if (Antal <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="centerbox1" style="width:90px; height:90px; border-radius:50%;">
  <div>
    <p id="myP">1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But since I need it to repeat itself again and again, I can't use ID and I want to switch the code to use "class" instead.

If I switch all my IDs to classes instead, the code no longer works.

```js
(function() {
  var Antal = document.getElementsByClassName('myP').innerHTML;


  if (Antal >= 6) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('centerbox1').style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
  } else
  if (Antal >= 1 && Antal < 5) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  } else
  if (Antal <= 0) {
    document.getElementByClassName("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="centerbox1">
  <div>
    <p class="myP">1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, this might be because of some very basic issue, but I hope someone can help me out since I'm kind of stuck at this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "s" in `getElement*s*ByClassName` should hint that something else might need to be done. But more importantly, how does your code know which one of the multiple elements to do? You will need to loop through the `.myP` elements, and use DOM traversal (eg. `parentNode`) to get to the container.

Comment: You have created a anonymous function but you did not run it

Comment: so if i understand you correctly you want to check the value of `myP` like every frame and if the value changed change the color? or do you want to have multiple circles on your page check the color?

Comment: `Antal` is a string so you have to convert it to a number before doing `Antal >= 6`

Comment: i want it to be used to show the "stock amout" in a webshop. Therefore i need it to be able to see whats in the '.myP' since that paragraph is where the information from the database is gonna be. I dont know if that makes much sense?

Comment: Try a couple of things,
1. did you run the anonymous function?
2. can you print the value in Antal with console.log? see perhaps you get nothing because the html have more tags with same id
3. can you print log inside the if blocks, see if you actually reach it?

Comment: i have to be honest, as i said, im not very strong in Javascript, so i not really sure how run "the anonymous function" or finding it in the console.log! Im very appriciative of all the answers, but have a hard time implimenting. 

If someone has an example of somthing similar i would love to see that! Hope you guys can bare over with me! 

thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the centerboxes and then find the p tag inside each box. Based on the p tag you can color the centerbox.

HTML

```
<div class="centerbox">
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="centerbox">
  <div>
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.centerbox {
  width:90px; 
  height:90px; 
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

JS

```
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("centerbox")
for(let i = 0;i<boxes.length;i++){
  let box = boxes.item(i)
  let content = box.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML
  let number = Number(content)
  if(number > 1) {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "green"
  }
}
```

You don't really need the anonymous function but if you want that, you need to add `()` at the end to make it auto-execute

```
(function() {
  console.log("executing!");
})();
```

Comment: You, my man, is a life saver! Thank you so much! 

This worked!

Answer (score 0):

the solution here is quite simple really.

Remember when working with getElement**s**ByClassName, javascript will return an array as there can be multiple classes. The solution is to use `getElementsByClassName[0]` as this will specifically return the first element that has that class in the array, obviously this also allows you to then specify which class you want to apply that to.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an array. Also, `getElementByClassName` does not exist.

Comment: This is correct, thanks for pointing out the getElementByClassName, my IDE was for some reason auto-predicting it.
With regards to what it returns, I simply used array as an easy explanation, but you're phrasing is more correct, thank you.